# Changing children elements when hovering the parent

Tags: html, css

I have my a container wich has a background image a title and button.

I want to hover on the container and change the title text-align to left, same as the button and display some information.

My question is if this is possible using only CSS3?

Here are the images of what I want to do:
[image]
[image]
(The name doesn't matter it's just an example)

Here's my HTML:

```
   <article class="destination__item destination__item--jacksonhole">
       <h2 class="destination__item--name">Jackson Hole</h2>
       <a href="#" class="destination__item--btn">Ver más</a>
   </article>
```

My CSS:

```
.destination__item {
    padding: 16em 0;
    text-align: center;
}
    .destination__item--canyons {
        background: url(../images/destinos/dest1.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .destination__item--name {
        color: white;
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding-bottom: .5em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .destination__item--btn {
        background-color: $color__red--primary;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 1em 2.5em;
        transition: all .5s ease;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        &:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: $color__red--dark;
            color: white;
        }
    }
```

To be honest, I have no idea where to start on the hover state, hope you guys can guide me a little bit.

Comment: There's a way to implement hovering in CSS http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp.  But if you want to dynamically display new information upon hover, then that'd require JQuery unless you hack some CSS in there and set the descriptions to hidden and then set them to visible upon hover I believe.

Comment: You mean to change a button's text to the left when its hovered?

Answer (score 0):

You can change other div on hover of other example:

```
.destination__item--jacksonhole:hover + destination__item--name{
        text-align: left;
 }
```

To change Content check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a8zp5jk/2/) , text on link is changed.

html:

```
 <article class="destination__item destination__item--jacksonhole">
       <h2 class="destination__item--name">Jackson Hole</h2>
       <a href="#" class="destination__item--btn"><span>Ver más<span></a>
   </article>
```

CSS:

```
.destination__item {
    padding: 16em 0;
    text-align: center;
}
    .destination__item--canyons {
        background: url(../images/destinos/dest1.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .destination__item--name {
        color:black;
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding-bottom: .5em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .destination__item--btn {
        background-color: $color__red--primary;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 1em 2.5em;
        transition: all .5s ease;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        &:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: $color__red--dark;
            color: white;
        }
    }
.destination__item:hover .destination__item--name,
.destination__item:hover .destination__item--btn {
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
}
.destination__item:hover .destination__item--btn span{
    display:none;
}
.destination__item:hover .destination__item--btn:after{
    content:"New Content"
}
```

Comment: @alex Did this help? or you are looking for something else?

Comment: This is working for the title, maybe I didn't explain myself, I want to hide the 3 blocks and on hover, show them I was wondering if that is possible using only CSS, thanks for helping me out solving this problem, regards!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, just add the following to your CSS:

```
.destination__item:hover .destination__item--name,
.destination__item:hover .destination__item--btn {
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/4a8zp5jk/) is a working example